# Getting average values with Android Profiler in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, mobile-development, android-profiler

I've been using android profiler to see how well my application performs on different devices and I was wondering if there's a way to automatically get average values such as average memory consumption in a set amount of time or for the entire duration of the profiling session. Peak values are easy to notice and mark down but an average would be very hard and time consuming to manually determine. I couldn't find any option that would allow me to easily get theses averages for me to make a report on how well my application performs in general.

I've tried searching for any examples on how to do this but haven't been able to find anything similar to what I'm trying to do.

Comment: This is not currently supported by the Android Studio Profiler. Can you open a feature request at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=192708&template=840533? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into [Firebase Performance Monitoring](https://firebase.google.com/docs/perf-mon/)?

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. I didn't know about it, I'll make sure to check it out.